# Trouble with updating table row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is a specific question.

I have a function below. I `echo` out the `$user` and the `$request` variables just to make sure that they're passed and I am using `gettype()` to check that they're both integers.

```
public function acceptRequest($user, $request){ 
    echo  $user   . $request ;
    $this->db->query("UPDATE test_requestBuddy SET accept = 'accepted' 
    WHERE user_requestId = $request AND user_responseId = $user ");
       echo 'success';        
 }
```

When I call this function

```
$test->acceptRequest(3,9);
```

It doesn't update. But when I replace `$request` and `$user` variables in MySQL with 3 and 9 like so

```
public function acceptRequest($user, $request){ 
    echo  $user   . $request ;
    $this->db->query("UPDATE test_requestBuddy SET accept = 'accepted' 
    WHERE user_requestId = 9 AND user_responseId = 3 "); // replace variables
       echo 'success';        
 }
```

It works. And the table is updated. So it's not an error with MySQL statement. Both my variables are integers. They're passed through the function. Why isn't my table row updating?

Comment: You're using mysqli, right?  did you try using prepared statements? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: ahhh, no, I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 $this->db->query("UPDATE test_requestBuddy SET accept = 'accepted' 
    WHERE user_requestId = '$request' AND user_responseId = '$user' ");
```

Or you can check mysql is running under strict mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQLi and Prepared statements:

```
public function acceptRequest($user, $request){ 
    echo  $user   . $request ;

    # NOTE Your db handle needs to be mysqli! 
    # http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php
    $mysqli = $this->db;

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE test_requestBuddy SET accept = 'accepted' 
    WHERE user_requestId = ? AND user_responseId = ? ")) {

        /* bind parameters - i ensures integers */
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $user, $request);

        /* execute query */
        $stmt->execute();

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();

        echo 'success';
     }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Joe T, using MySQLi would be the best technique here - as you don't want to fall victim to SQL injection. Assuming the request and response are integers within your database:

```
$query = ("UPDATE test_requestBuddy SET accept = 'accepted' 
WHERE user_requestId = ? AND user_responseId = ? ");
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $request, $user);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result();
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
```

However for the sake of your question, encasing your variables like: {$variable} would ensure the sql statement is ran correctly:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE test_requestBuddy SET accept = 'accepted' 
WHERE user_requestId = {$request} AND user_responseId = {$user} ");
```